# a funktion that behaves in the way of acceleration at start, and a constant force after a set time..

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

How id like the funktion to behave, acceleration at start, and a constant force after a set amount of time

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgIH1.png]

All i want is a funktion that behave this way, il edit it myself if need be to fit for its purpose..

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose your function to be $y(x)=\tanh{x}$, for $x\geq 0$. This function is bounded by the line $y=1$.